# While performing the time Series Analysis I have got the error Date time while converting the string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have the data which is in the column of date and  I want to convert into DateTime, an error occurs like the below

```
    Month   Sales of shampoo over a three year period
0   1-01    266.0
1   1-02    145.9
2   1-03    183.1
3   1-04    119.3
4   1-05    180.3

pd.to_datetime(data['Month'])
```

Error:-

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00
```

what should I in this case:-

Comment: what is the "month" column format? Does it "month-day"?

Comment: here the `1` representing the year and `02` representing the months of that year

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a zero-padding problem. If you use "01" instead of "1" you can convert the object to DateTime.

Just like this;

```
x=['1-01','1-02','1-03','1-04','1-05']
y=[266.0,145.9,183.1,119.3,180.3]
data=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x,y)),columns=['month','sth'])
data['month']='0'+data['month']
data['month']=pd.to_datetime(data['month'],format='%y-%m')
data['month']=data['month'].dt.strftime('%y-%m') # to convert 2-digits
```

Comment: the OP's input seems to be '1-01', not '01-01'. so you might want to add `data['month'] = '0' + data['month']`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
pd.to_datetime(data['Month'], format="%y-%m")
```

Comment: here `1` is representing the year and 05 and 06 so on representing the months

Comment: I changed my answer. I think this is what you want.